# How to remove specific time ranges, from a set of time ranges in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

With this example set of timestamp ranges:

```
WITH sessions AS (
  (
  SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP('2022-09-24 13:49:32+0100') AS start,
    TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26 02:06:17+0100') AS end
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26 08:42:19+0100'), 
    TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26 09:41:40+0100'),  

  UNION ALL
 
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26 09:53:06+0100'),
    TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26 11:20:34+0100'))
)

SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE....
```

How would I go about removing all time between Fridays 17:00, America/New_York and Monday 09:00 Asia/Shanghai?

I really can't seem to figure this out.

"Best" thing I can think of is generating a table with all Friday/Monday ranges, and joining against that table, using the standard Gaps and Islands solution, is that really the best way?

Thanks!

Edit:

The context is wait and resolution times for a ticketing system, where only time within the open operating hours should count. The service is staffed by various international teams, so the services operating hours become more complicated.

I would expect the results to look like this:

```
Start                     End                       Status
2022-09-24 13:49:32+0100  2022-09-26 02:00:00+0100  Closed
2022-09-26 02:00:00+0100  2022-09-26 02:06:17+0100  Open
2022-09-26 08:42:19+0100  2022-09-26 09:41:40+0100  Open
2022-09-26 09:53:06+0100  2022-09-26 11:20:34+0100  Open
```

Because the part of the 26th is within the working hours of Shanghai.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *removing all times between...*. Could you show the result that you expect for your sample data, along with a short explanation?

Comment: Edited and added sample output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Monday 09:00 Asia/Shanghai corresponds to Sunday 21:00 America/New_York I came up with the following (I only filtered by the column `start`, if necessary you can apply the same to `end`):

```sql
WITH sessions AS (
  (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2022-09-24T13:49:32+0100') AS `start`, TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T02:06:17+0100') AS `end` UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T08:42:19+0100'), TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T09:41:40+0100'),  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T09:53:06+0100'), TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T11:20:34+0100')) 
)

SELECT *
FROM sessions 
WHERE 
  NOT (
    (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') = 6 AND EXTRACT(TIME FROM start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') > TIME(17, 0, 0))
    OR 
    (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') = 7)
    OR 
    (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') = 1 AND EXTRACT(TIME FROM start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') < TIME(21, 0, 0))
  )
```

Short explanation: 
`DAYOFWEEK` gives you the weekday, Sundays being `1` ([see docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract)). For Friday and Sunday I also compare the times with the thresholds and exclude them from the results, Saturday I exclude completely.

**Edit after comments:**

The following will exclude all periods that fall in the closed time. Periods that overlap with the closed time are truncated. Only periods in open time are returned. Added a few comments for explaining the query:

```
-- Assuming closed period in UTC is from Friday 22:00 to Monday 01:00
-- Assuming start and end do not span over the closed period

WITH sessions AS (
  (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2022-09-24T13:49:32+0100') AS `start`, TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T02:06:17+0100') AS `end` UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T08:42:19+0100'), TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T09:41:40+0100'),  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2022-09-23T08:42:19+0100'), TIMESTAMP('2022-09-25T09:41:40+0100'),  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T09:53:06+0100'), TIMESTAMP('2022-09-26T11:20:34+0100')) 
)

SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN start_offset IS NOT NULL THEN TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start), EXTRACT(DAY FROM start), 1, 0, 0)), INTERVAL start_offset DAY) 
  ELSE start
  END as new_start, -- using the determined offset, time is fixed
CASE 
  WHEN end_offset IS NOT NULL THEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `end`), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `end`), EXTRACT(DAY FROM `end`), 22, 0, 0)), INTERVAL end_offset DAY)
  ELSE `end`
  END as new_end, -- using the determined offset, time is fixed
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  *,
  CASE 
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start) = 6 AND EXTRACT(TIME FROM start) > TIME(22, 0, 0)) THEN 3
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start) = 7) THEN 2
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start) = 1) THEN 1
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start) = 2 AND EXTRACT(TIME FROM start) < TIME(1, 0, 0)) THEN 0
    ELSE NULL
    END AS start_offset, -- determine how many days to offset the start (adding to start date)
  CASE 
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM `end`) = 6 AND EXTRACT(TIME FROM `end`) > TIME(22, 0, 0)) THEN 0
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM `end`) = 7) THEN 1
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM `end`) = 1) THEN 2
    WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM `end`) = 2 AND EXTRACT(TIME FROM `end`) < TIME(1, 0, 0)) THEN 3
    ELSE NULL
    END AS end_offset, -- determine how many days to offset the end (subtracting from end date)
  FROM sessions
)
WHERE NOT (start_offset IS NOT NULL AND end_offset IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This would exclude the entire time span where anything between Start and End overlaps. I want to exclude only the exclusion bit, ie your example would exclude the full range in the first row, but it should be including a bunch of hours on the 25th. 

2022-09-25 17:00+0100 - 2022-09-26T02:06:17+0100 should all be included.

Comment: I thought I understood what you want, but now I don't anymore. `2022-09-25 17:00:00+0100` would be `2022-09-26T00:00:00` Asia/Shanghai time. A monday before 9:00, why include it? `2022-09-26T02:06:17+0100` is included in the results if you run my query and add it to the WITH clause.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm confusing myself when converting back and forth. 2022-09-26 02:00:00+0100 - 2022-09-26 02:06:17+0100 is the time in the example that should be included. I updated my question with sample output /explanation

Comment: I still don't get what the issue is. Those times are included in the results if you use my query.

Comment: yours does not include the span 2022-09-26 02:00:00+0100 - 2022-09-26 02:06:17+0100

Comment: Jeez! Put it in the WITH clause and it's included, I'm not going to do it for you.

Comment: No, that's not the issue... The overlapping hours need to be removed. Eg. if you had 2022-10-06 00:00:00 - 2022-10-20 00:00:00 as one span, then from this span both set of weekend hours should be removed, in practice creating 2 new ranges.

Comment: I finally got what you mean, not quite clear from your question itself. I like the challenge and edited my answer, solution is making some assumptions, hope it helps anyway.